# Why does rails database id keep counting forward after destroying an intermediate item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database, rails-migrations

The title might not be so clear, and anyway it's better to just look at this:

My sequence of creating/destroying items A, B and C is:

1. Create A --> `id:1`
2. Create B --> `id:2`
3. Destroy B
4. Create C --> `id:3`

I've already destroyed B, C should be counted as `id:2` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying database column for `id` is set to autoincrement. The id is generated at the database level, not by `ActiveRecord`. If you want to know more, read up on SQL sequences or [autoincrement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) .